# How can I connect functions on an hpp and cpp file into qt design studio?

Tags: c++, user-interface, qml, qt-creator, qt-design-studio

I am currently working on a project where my task is to work on the development of the UI, which I have never done before. I am encountering a lot of issues, especially with merging files from my other teammates who are working in hpp and cpp files and I must take the functions in those files to create a functional UI.

For example, what I am currently working on is creating the desktop application for the login of users, and some teammates have created functions for password encryption and authentication mechanisms that I need to merge. I notice that the files on QT creator are just .ui while on QT Design studio they are ui.qml (maybe it is the root of the problem but I don't know how to fix it)

I have already tried to add the hpp and cpp files on QT Design studio (version 6.4 of everything) but I don't see any places where I could add them and merge them. Then I tried opening and running the QT Design Studio login file on QT creator and it does not run, it just gives errors that I do not understand, such as: ":-1: error: ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed."

Is it possible to do so on QT Design Studio? If so how? If not, how do I transfer my work done on QT design studio onto QT creator? Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

QT Design studio is just for `UI` designing...
The general workflow with QT C++ and QML is
to create the logic in C++ and call that logic from QML.

That is usually done via:

- [backends](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-topic.html)
- [registering C++ types to the qml engine.](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qqmlengine.html#qmlRegisterSingletonType-1)

Note that anything that you want to expose to QML
must exist in a [`QML_ELEMENT`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qqmlengine.html#QML_ELEMENT) or `Q_GADGET` class.
callables must be either [`slot`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/signalsandslots.html) or [`Q_INVOKABLE`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qobject.html#Q_INVOKABLE)
and variables must be [`property`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/properties.html)

[This guide](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-6.4/qtqml-cppintegration-exposecppattributes.html) is a good introduction.